# Bootstrap div height 100%?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How could I have the first section be the height of the browser window on this template? http://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/velocity/1.5.4

Apparently the class that I have to update is `promo section section-on-bg` it isn't working. I also tried `min-height 100%, height 100%`.

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: Where did you get the information about those classes? You need to provide all relevant information here, in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.promo,
.bg-slider-wrapper .flexslider .slide {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

best thing I can advice you would be using vh, which represents % of display height(http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) so your code would be

```
.div {
    height:100vh;
}
```